# Restore tf variables in a different graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use my pretrained `separable convolution` (which is a part of a bigger module) in another separable convolution in a other model.
In the trained module I tried

```
with tf.variable_scope('sep_conv_ker' + str(input_shape[-1])):
            sep_conv2d = tf.reshape(
            tf.layers.separable_conv2d(inputs_flatten,input_shape[-1] , 
            [1,input_shape[-2]]
            trainable=trainable),
            [inputs_flatten.shape[0],1,input_shape[-1],INNER_LAYER_WIDTH])
```

and

```
        all_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
        scope1_variables = tf.contrib.framework.filter_variables(all_variables, include_patterns=['sep_conv_ker'])
        sep_conv_weights_saver = tf.train.Saver(scope1_variables, sharded=True, max_to_keep=20)
```

Inside `sess.run`

```
sep_conv_weights_saver.save(sess,os.path.join(LOG_DIR + MODEL_SPEC_LOG_DIR,
                                                              "init_weights",MODEL_SPEC_SUFFIX + 'epoch_' + str(epoch) + '.ckpt'))
```

But I cannot understand when and how should I load the weights to the `separable convolution` in the other module, it has different name, and different scope,
Furthermore, as I'm using a defined `tf.layer` does it mean I need to access each individual weight in the new graph and assign it?

My current solution **doesn't work** and I think that the weights are being initialized after the assignment somehow
 Furthermore, loading a whole new graph just for few weights seems weird, isn't it?

```
        ###IN THE OLD GRAPH###
        all_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
        scope1_variables = tf.contrib.framework.filter_variables(all_variables, include_patterns=['sep_conv_ker'])
        vars = dict((var.op.name.split("/")[-1] + str(idx), var) for idx,var in enumerate(scope1_variables))
        sep_conv_weights_saver = tf.train.Saver(vars, sharded=True, max_to_keep=20)
```

In the new graph is a function that basiclly takes the variables from the old graph and assigning them, loading the meta_graph is redundant

```
def load_pretrained(sess):
    sep_conv2d_vars = [var for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES) if ("sep_conv_ker" in var.op.name)]
    var_dict = dict((var.op.name.split("/")[-1] + str(idx), var) for idx, var in enumerate(sep_conv2d_vars))
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
        tf.train.latest_checkpoint('log/train/sep_conv_ker/global_neighbors40/init_weights') + '.meta')
    # saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=var_dict)
    new_saver.restore(sess,
                      tf.train.latest_checkpoint('log/train/sep_conv_ker/global_neighbors40/init_weights'))

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    sep_conv2d_trained = dict(("".join(var.op.name.split("/")[-2:]),var) for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES) if ("sep_conv_ker_init" in var.op.name))
    for var in sep_conv2d_vars:
        tf.assign(var,sep_conv2d_trained["".join(var.op.name.split("/")[-2:])])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the variables have the same in the variable file and in the graph where you load the variables. You can write a script that will convert the variables names.

1. With `tf.contrib.framework.list_variables(ckpt)`, you can find out what variables of what shapes you have in the checkpoint and create respective variables with the new names (I believe, you can write a regex that will fix the names) and correct shape.
2. Then you load the original variables with `tf.contrib.framework.load_checkpoint(ckpt)` assign ops `tf.assign(var, loaded)` that will assigning the variables with new names with the saved values.
3. Runn the assign ops in a session.
4. Save the new variables.

**Minimum example:**

Original model (variables in scope "regression"):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3]) 
regression = tf.layers.dense(x, 1, name="regression")

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())

saver.save(session, './model')
```

Renaming script:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

assign_ops = []
reader = tf.contrib.framework.load_checkpoint("./model")
for name, shape in tf.contrib.framework.list_variables("./model"):
    new_name = name.replace("regression/", "foo/bar/")
    new_var = tf.get_variable(new_name, shape)
    assign_ops.append(tf.assign(new_var, reader.get_tensor(name)))

session = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())

session.run(assign_ops)
saver.save(session, './model-renamed')
```

Model where you load the renamed variables (the same variables in score "foo/bar"):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3]) 
    regression = tf.layers.dense(x, 1, name="bar")

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())

saver.restore(session, './model-renamed')
```

Comment: Because the graphs are different, I get 'a mismatch between the current graph and the graph' when trying to load from ckpt

Comment: Yes, indeed. What I am suggesting is writing a separate script that will rename the saved variables according to how they will be named in the new graph, save them into a file and load them a script with your different new graph. You also need to make sure that the savers on both sides only the variables you are interested in.

Comment: Please see my edited question, I think that I did what you suggested, but it loads the meta graph of the old graph, where I would prefer to only load the weights values. when I try to call the saver with ckpt without loading the meta graph I get the "not the same graph" error as mentioned

Comment: If you could show a minimal snippet that would be super helpful, as, even after changing the weigh names I get a mismatch between that graphs (I think the meta compares the weights and other data in other ways than just weight names)

Comment: I added the minimum example. You don't need to deal with the graphs at all. If you know what variables are those you want to transfer, the only thing you need to know are their names in the original and in the new model.

Comment: That's awesome, and exactly what I needed.